# How many time can you use a free 14 day ps+ trial after creating an account?

Tags: playstation-plus

I have already used one trial on my main account and used another trial on a second account. So how many time can I do this?

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, I would note that I have used multiple trial codes on one Xbox account (everything from 48 hour codes to the full month trials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have changed in the meantime, but the last time I checked (January 2014) it is impossible to redeem the free 14 day PS Plus trial for an account that has had PS Plus before.

I've received 30 days of PS Plus for free in 2011 as an apology for the 2011 PSN hack, and haven't been able to redeem the 14 day trial since, nor did I ever redeem it before.

Whether this also applies to trial codes shipped in some games, I can't say (probably not). I've yet to see a PS3/PS4 game that ships with such a code.

Comment: How many times can you create a new profile and activate the 14 day trial?

Comment: @ethio. [You can not create more than 64 accounts on a PS3, even if you delete or deactivate old accounts.](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/335/~/maximum-number-of-accounts-allowed-on-ps3) So on a PS3, you can redeem up to 64 * 14 days of free PS Plus. So 896 free days in total; about 2 years and 5 months. As for the PS4, [the number appears to be 100](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-4-Support/Maximum-number-of-accounts-allowed-on-PS4/td-p/44735563). 1400 days; about 3 years and a little less than 10 months.

Comment: @ethio. As for the PS Vita, I believe accounts are bound to the memory card, so you'll need 1 memory card per account. So if you want more free PS Plus, you'll need to buy a new PS3/PS4 after reaching your lifetime limit.

Comment: @ethio. Keep in mind that you probably only need to redeem the 14 days once a month (assuming you're only interested in the free games), so you can benefit from PS Plus for 64, resp. 100 months; about 5 years 4 months, or 8 years 4 months.

Comment: Keep in mind that free games are tied to the account they were downloaded with, not the PS3/PS4 they were downloaded to.